# Error in Sitecore.FXM.Pipelines.SaveUI.RemoveDeletedClientActionsProcessor - Sitecore Experience Editor while saving

Tags: experience-editor

So i get a weird error in Experience editor while saving. it says "An Error Occurred" and I cant understand really what's happening. 
I looked at the logs and all i can see is a very generic exception. Any pointers or tips would greatly help.

> Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException Message:
>   Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. Source:
>   mscorlib    at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target,
>   Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj,
>   Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   at Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.InvokeMethod(MethodInfo method,
>   Object[] parameters, Object obj)    at
>   Sitecore.Nexus.Pipelines.NexusPipelineApi.Resume(PipelineArgs args,
>   Pipeline pipeline)    at
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.Pipeline.Start(PipelineArgs args, Boolean atomic)
>   at
>   Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Ribbon.Requests.SaveItem.CallServerSavePipeline.ProcessRequest()
>   at
>   Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Server.Requests.PipelineProcessorRequest`1.Process(RequestArgs
>   requestArgs)
>
> Nested Exception
>
> Exception: System.NullReferenceException Message: Object reference not
>   set to an instance of an object. Source: Sitecore.FXM    at
>   Sitecore.FXM.Pipelines.SaveUI.RemoveDeletedClientActionsProcessor.Process(SaveArgs
>   args)

Comment: The best way I’ve found to debug these errors is to copy the out of the box CallServerSavePipeline and then patch in your copy in place of it and attach the debugger locally (assuming you can replicate locally that is). I’ve seen issues in the past with certain field data such as final renderings etc causing failures.

Comment: Thanks @AdamSeabridge i was just doing the same thing.. lol..  was getting a little lazy and wanted to see if anyone had been through that path..